# Javascript prevent underlying click when hiding overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an application that runs on desktop and mobile that has a div and when the user either clicks or taps outside of the div it hides. This div is on top of other elements and the issue I'm running into is when the user taps outside of the div it does hide, but then it also performs the click event on an element that is below it. This functionality works fine on desktop when calling the `mousedown` event. The code that I added in is:

```
$(document).on( "mousedown touchstart", function(e){
    if (isSearchOpen) {
        if (!$(searchContainer).is(e.target) && $(searchContainer).has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('input[name=q]','form[name=searchFormMobile]').val('');
            $('input[name=q]','form[name=searchForm]').val('');
            $(searchOverlay).hide();
            isSearchOpen = false;
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried calling `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation()`, and `return false;` within the second `if-statement` and none of those work. This pop up can appear on mulitple "pages" so I would like to avoid trying to capture any possible element that can be clicked on and handling this issue that way if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: click isn't the same as mousedown event. So the default for mousedown will be controlled but not for a click. You should perform the hiding on mouseup, click or touchend.

Comment: you can consider having a transparent modal layer, which would disable the background , while your div is visible, so when user clicks outside your div, hide modal as well along with div

Comment: What is the element that is "below" it? What does the HTML look like? You say it works fine on desktop, so is it only not working on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a blur event to your div instead. Whenever a user clicks or taps outside of the div, an event fires off.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Answer (score 0):

Append a transparent div with full screen width and height with `z-Index` 100, and for your `DIV`, give the `z-Index` as 101. For Onclick event on the overlay `DIV`, remove both the DIVs from DOM. FYI, jquery-Ui modal dialog does the same. ;)